# Does it matter on which control you call the DoDragDrop method?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, drag-and-drop

I'm wondering if it makes any difference on which control I call the DoDragDrop method in a Windows Forms Application.

I have a Form with two PictureBox controls. One can be dragged and the other one has its AllowsDrop property set to true.

The MouseDown event handler for the draggable PictureBox is as follows:

```
    private void dragPictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is PictureBox)
        {
            var pictureBox = (PictureBox) sender;
            var effect = pictureBox.DoDragDrop(
                pictureBox.Image, DragDropEffects.All);
            MessageBox.Show("Drag ended in a " + effect);
        }
    }
```

But in stead of calling DoDragDrop on the pictureBox, I seems like I can use any control, for instance the Form itself

```
var effect = this.DoDragDrop(pictureBox.Image, DragDropEffects.All);
```

or even

```
var effect = label1.DoDragDrop(pictureBox.Image, DragDropEffects.All);
```

Does it make any difference on which control I call the DoDragDrop method? And if so, what's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very well documented, but I believe it effects which control would have the [QueryContinueDrag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.querycontinuedrag.aspx) event raised on it.

All of the examples tend to use the source of the drag data, so I'd stick with using that.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The same goes for the GiveFeedback event. Interestingly enough, both events keeps occuring during the drag operation, even though the documentation states it only occurs when there is a change in the keyboard or mouse button state.